# Is my Task long running if it is fully async?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

Consider such code:

```
private static async Task ProcessSomethingAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var message = await GetMessageAsync();
        await WriteAsync(message);
    }
}
```

Consider that *GetMessageAsync* and *WriteAsync* methods leverage asynchronous IO.

Imagine that I have several(from 2 to N) tasks like this, which live as long as application lives.
To my opinion, since the code inside the loop is fully async, it is better not to use LongRunning option when I start such tasks, so that we will be able to leverage ThreadPool instead of creating thread per Task.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: If those methods are actually asynchronous I/O, not CPU-bound, they could live just fine inside one thread. If the main thread isn't preoccupied, of course, but even then you'd just execute all this in another single thread.

Comment: How likely is it that `GetMessageAsync()` and/or `WriteAsync()` will actually complete synchronously? Remember, if they actually complete synchronously, the `await` doesn't actually represent a point in time when the thread will actually be relinquished.

Comment: @presiuslitelsnoflek agree, terms async and long running are orthogonal, but maybe I should change the question to be more specific.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am not sure if I am following. First we read, then we write.

Comment: Even in the circumstances where async I/O is happening, there can be cases where the system can respond, essentially, with "you know what? I can actually do that right now. There, it's done" and so (up at this level) the `Task` than either of those methods returns might already be completed by the time your code gets hold of it. And so no actual waiting has to occur, and the code carries right on past the `await` point. So, we'd need to know how likely it is that both of these methods might actually do this.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is it really possible with network IO? The question was asked with the idea that await will actually register a callback on the threadpool

Comment: Well, the problem now is that you keep changing context. From the initial question, it was totally unclear in what way the async methods that you were calling might work, and so its perfectly reasonable to ask how frequently they might accomplish their tasks synchronously. Then we shifted slightly to "they're performing async I/O", but still, there can be circumstances where these may complete synchronously. Now, we shifted slight further, and it's now *network* I/O. Do you see now, though, why the question of "how often might these methods complete synchronously?" is still *relevant*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sorry if my question seems to be not clear. I was thinking that the code is more or less self-explain the idea. Re: your comment, I see what you are asking for. If we imagine that all of the _awaits_ are done without a call back, that task becomes naturally long running and here I would think of LongRunning option. Having said all of this(awaits are always thorugh a callback), I think my approach is correct. By the way, I am really not aware of internal implementation - when async IO through network or hard drive can be finished synchronosly?

Comment: Well, one example of where IO through the network might complete synchronously is that you ask for, say, 10 bytes, but 10 bytes have already been received and are just sitting in a (system) buffer waiting to be copied into your buffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it is better not to use LongRunning option when I start such tasks, so that we will be able to leverage ThreadPool instead of creating thread per Task.

When you're running `async` code, you should not specify `LongRunning`. If you do, then (as of today's implementation), the thread pool will start a new thread just to run the first part of your `async` code. As soon as your code yields at an `await`, that new thread will be disposed and the rest of the code will run on regular thread pool threads. So, `LongRunning` is usually counterproductive for `async` code.

I have a blog post on why [`StartNew` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), and I (briefly) cover all of the `TaskCreationOptions` in that post:

> AttachedToParent shouldn't be used in async tasks, so that's out. DenyChildAttach should *always* be used with async tasks (hint: if you didn't already know that, then StartNew isn't the tool you need). DenyChildAttach is passed by Task.Run. HideScheduler might be useful in some really obscure scheduling scenarios but in general should be avoided for async tasks. That only leaves LongRunning and PreferFairness, which are both optimization hints that should only be specified after application profiling. I often see LongRunning misused in particular. In the vast majority of situations, the threadpool will adjust to any long-running task in 0.5 seconds - *without* the LongRunning flag. Most likely, you don't really need it.

Comment: What's interesting, `LongRunning` appears to start a plain thread, not a pool thread. `Thread.IsThreadPoolThread` is `false` for it. So it'd start instantly even when there's `ThreadPool` starvation.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. I've seen your article as well. Thank you.

Comment: @Noseratio The ThreadPool is meant for relatively short pieces of code, so it makes sense that code that is explicitly marked as long running won't run there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, specifying LongRunning will potentially allow more threads to be created, because you are telling the scheduler that your task is going to hog a thread for a long time.

Async methods are exactly the opposite, they free up the thread to do other things without blocking.